# Convert "0" and "1" strings in a multi-level list to integers

Tags: python

I have a 3 level list of strings and need to convert the "0" and "1" strings into integers. I tried it like this but I am not getting the wanted result

```
for list in a:
    for sublist in list:
        for item in sublist:    
            if item == "0" or item == "1":
                item == int(item)
```

What am I missing? I tested it in different ways and I suspect the last line of code is wrong.

Comment: You have to assign the converted item back to the original sub-sub list.  All you have done so far is assign it to a temporary variable that gets overwritten on the next iteration.

Comment: Two more things: In your last line, you use `==`, which is not appropriate for assignments. Second, never ever use `list` for a variable name!!!! **NEVER**!

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign the converted item back to the original sub-sub list. All you have done so far is assign it to a temporary variable that gets overwritten on the next iteration.

Also, try to avoid using `list` as a variable.

Try this:

```
for sublist in a:
    for subsublist in sublist:
        for i, item in enuerate(subsublist):    
            if item == "0" or item == "1":
                subsublist[i] = int(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

recursive ver.

```
def foo(l):
  res = []
  for ele in l:
    if type(ele) == list:
      res += foo(ele)
    else:
      if ele in ['1','0']:
        res += [int(ele)]
      else:
        res += [ele]
  return res
```